Surjection onto endomorphisms of multiplicative group of a field
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p > 0$. Denote by $k^\times$ the multiplicative group of $k$.  There is a ring homomorphism given by restriction to $k^\times$
$$
\mathbb{Z}\mathrm{End}(k) \to \mathrm{End}(k^\times),
$$
where, on the left hand side, $\mathrm{End}{(k)}$ is field endomorphisms, and $\mathrm{End}(k^\times)$ is endomorphisms of the multiplicative group $k^\times$. For example, if $\theta \in \mathrm{End}(k)$, then $p\theta \mapsto \theta \circ \mathrm{Fr}$.
Recall that the ring structure on $\mathrm{End}(k^\times)$ is given as follows:
$$
(\lambda + \mu)(x) = \lambda(x)\mu(x), \quad (\lambda \cdot \mu)(x) = \lambda(\mu(x))
$$
for $x \in k^\times$.
Question: Is the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\mathrm{End}(k) \to \mathrm{End}(k^\times)$ surjective?
It is surjective when $k$ is a finite field, however I don't expect this to be the case generally. But (at least to me) this is not easy to see. Even the case where $k = \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is still not obvious after writing down what $\mathrm{End}(k)$ and $\mathrm{End}(k^\times)$ are.

EDIT. As @YCor points out in the comments, the ring structure here might not be so relevant. The question is essentially equivalent to asking if every endomorphism $f$ of $k^\times$ there is finitely many field endomorphisms $u_i, v_i$ such that $f = \sum u_i - \sum v_i$. Let us write the above morphism more explicity, an arbitrary element $\sum e_i \theta_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}\mathrm{End}(k)$ goes to
$$ 
\sum e_i \theta_i \longmapsto \Big( x \mapsto \prod_{i} \theta_i(x)^{e_i} \Big), \quad x \in k^\times.
$$
So the question is if every endomorphism of $k^\times$ can be written as the right hand side of the above, for some $e_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and field endomorphisms $\theta_i$.

I'm not sure where the ring structure occurs. It seems that the question is equivalent to whether for every group endomorphism $f$ of $k^*$ there are $m,n$, endomorphisms $u_1,\dots,u_m$, $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $k$ such that $f=\sum u_i -\sum v_j$.

@YCor, I'm more sure if the ring structure is terribly important here. I agree that the question is equivalent to the one you describe here. Thanks, have edited!

Indeed, my additive notation was confusing, I should have written multiplicatively $f=\prod_i u_i / \prod_j v_j$.

This is false for every algebraically closed field $k$ of positive characteristic. A previous version of this answer needed a conjecture on the existence of primes $\ell$ in which $p$ has very small order, on which I asked a new question. However, I have now found an unconditional argument.
In general, note that an endomorphism $\phi \colon k \to k$ is always injective (being a morphism of fields). If $\operatorname{tr.deg}(k/\mathbf F_p)$ is finite, then $\phi$ is algebraic for transcendence degree reasons, hence surjective since $k$ is algebraically closed. (Of course this fails in general: there is a non-surjective endomorphism of $\overline{\mathbf F_p(t_1,t_2,\ldots)}$ induced by $t_i \mapsto t_{i+1}$.)
There is an immediate reduction to the case $k = \bar{\mathbf F}_p$. Indeed, if $\ell$ is any algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ and $k \subseteq \ell$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbf F_p$ in $\ell$, then $k^\times = (\ell^\times)_{\text{tors}}$, so every endomorphism of $\ell^\times$ induces an endomorphism of $k^\times$. Since the same holds for endomorphisms of $\ell$ and $k$, we get a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc} \mathbf Z[\operatorname{End}(\ell)] & \to & \operatorname{End}(\ell^\times) \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \mathbf Z[\operatorname{End}(k)] & \to & \operatorname{End}(k^\times).\! \end{array}$$
Since $k^\times$ is divisible, every homomorphism $k^\times \to k^\times$ extends to a homomorphism $\ell^\times \to k^\times$, so the right vertical map is surjective. Thus if the top map is surjective, so is the bottom map, so it suffices to show that this fails when $k = \bar{\mathbf F}_p$.
If $k = \bar{\mathbf F}_p$, we see that $\operatorname{End}(k) \cong \hat{\mathbf Z}$ by Galois theory, and $\operatorname{End}(k^\times) \cong \hat{\mathbf Z}{}^{(p')} = \prod_{\ell \neq p} \mathbf Z_\ell$. Under these identifications, the map $\operatorname{End}(k) \to \operatorname{End}(k^\times)$ is the inclusion $p^{\hat{\mathbf Z}} \hookrightarrow \hat{\mathbf Z}{}^{(p')}$ (which makes sense as $p$ is a unit in $\hat{\mathbf Z}{}^{(p')}$).
Lemma. Let $p$ be a prime. For $n > 1$, write $\Phi_n$ for the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial. If $q \neq r$ are primes not dividing $p(p-1)$, then $\Phi_q(p)$ and $\Phi_r(p)$ are coprime.
Proof. It suffices to show that no prime $\ell$ divides both $\Phi_q(p)$ and $\Phi_r(p)$. Note that $\ell^n \mid p^q-1$ if and only if $\ell \neq p$ and the order of $p$ modulo $\ell^n$ is either $1$ or $q$.

If $\ell \mid p-1$, then $\ell \neq q,r$. If $n = v_\ell(p-1)$, then the order of $p$ modulo $\ell^{n+1}$ is $\ell$ since $\ker\!\big((\mathbf Z/\ell^{n+1}\mathbf Z)^\times \to (\mathbf Z/\ell^n\mathbf Z)^\times\big) \cong \mathbf Z/\ell\mathbf Z$, so $\ell^{n+1}$ does not divide $p^q-1$ (resp. $p^r-1$) as $p$ has order $q$ (resp. $r$) modulo $p^q-1$ (resp. $p^r-1$). Thus, $\ell$ divides neither $\Phi_q(p)$ nor $\Phi_r(p)$.
If $\ell \nmid p-1$, then $\ell \mid \Phi_q(p)$ if and only if the order of $p$ modulo $\ell$ is exactly $q$, which can happen for at most one prime $q$. $\square$

Lemma. The subset $p^{\hat{\mathbf Z}}$ does not generate $\hat{\mathbf Z}{}^{(p')}$.
Proof. By the lemma above and the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the map
$$\hat{\mathbf Z}{}^{(p')} \to \prod_{q \nmid p(p-1)} \mathbf Z/\Phi_q(p)\mathbf Z\label{1}\tag{1}$$
is surjective. For each $q \nmid p(p-1)$, define $a_q \in \mathbf Z/\Phi_q(p)\mathbf Z$ as follows: let $r = \lfloor \log_{2q+1}(\Phi_q(p)-1) \rfloor$ be the largest integer such that $(2q+1)^r < \Phi_q(p)$. The subgroup $\langle p,-1\rangle$ of $(\mathbf Z/\Phi_q(p)\mathbf Z)^\times$ generated by $p$ and $-1$ has order $\leq 2q$. Since $\Phi_q(p) > (2q+1)^r$, we can choose $a_q \in \mathbf Z/\Phi_q(p)\mathbf Z$ that cannot be written as $\sum_{i=1}^r b_i$ for $b_i \in \langle p,-1\rangle \cup \{0\}$. Let $a \in \hat{\mathbf Z}{}^{(p')}$ be a lift of $(a_q)_q$ along the map \eqref{1}.
We claim that $a$ is not in the span of $p^{\hat{\mathbf Z}}$. Indeed, if it were equal to $\sum_{i=1}^d \varepsilon_i p^{n_i}$ for $n_i \in \hat{\mathbf Z}$ and $\varepsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\}$, choose a prime $q > p$ such that $\Phi_q(p) > (2q+1)^d$, which is possible as $\tfrac{p^n-1}{p-1} \gg (2n+1)^d$ for $n \gg 0$. If $r = \lfloor \log_{2q+1}(\Phi_q(p)-1) \rfloor$ as above, we conclude that $r \geq d$. But the image of $p^{n_i}$ modulo $\Phi_q(p)$ lands in the subgroup $\langle p \rangle$ of $\mathbf Z/\Phi_q(p)\mathbf Z$, and by construction, the residue of $a$ modulo $\Phi_q(p)$ cannot be written as a sum $\sum_{i=1}^r b_i$ for $b_i \in \langle p,-1\rangle \cup \{0\}$. Setting $b_i = \varepsilon_i p^{n_i} \pmod{\Phi_q(p)}$ for $i \leq d$ and $b_i = 0$ for $i > d$ gives a contradiction. $\square$
On the other hand, for every finite set $S$ of primes $\neq p$, the subgroup $p^{\hat{\mathbf Z}} \subseteq \prod_{\ell \in S} \mathbf Z_\ell^\times$ does generate $\prod_{\ell \in S} \mathbf Z_\ell$. Indeed, $p^{\hat{\mathbf Z}}$ is open (you can for instance use the $\ell$-adic logarithm to show $\mathbf Z_\ell^\times \cong \mathbf F_p^\times \times \mathbf Z_\ell$, so any closed subgroup is open). Then the subgroup of $\prod_{\ell \in S}\mathbf Z_\ell$ generated by $p^{\hat{\mathbf Z}}$ is also open, hence closed and of finite index, hence everything since the map to $\prod_{\ell \in S} \mathbf Z/\ell \cong \mathbf Z/\prod_{\ell \in S} \ell\mathbf Z$ is surjective as we certainly have the element $1$.

Thanks, Remy. Sorry if this is standard notation and hence a silly question. Just to clarify, what is $p^{\hat{\mathbf{Z}}}$?

If $a \in \mathbf N$, then the residue of $p^a$ modulo $n$ (assumed not divisible by $p$) depends only on the residue of $a$ modulo $\phi(n)$. Thus, if $a = (a_n){n \in \mathbf N} \in \hat{\mathbf Z} = \lim_n \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$, we can define $p^a \in \hat{\mathbf Z}{}^{(p')}$ to be the element $(p^{a{\phi(n)}}){n \in \mathbf N} \in \hat{\mathbf Z}{}^{(p')}=\lim{(p,n) = 1} \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$. Then $p^{\hat{\mathbf Z}}$ is the set ${p^a\ |\ a \in \hat{\mathbf Z}}$. It should coincide with the closure of $p^{\mathbf Z}$, at least inside the unit group of $\hat{\mathbf Z}{}^{(p')}$.

In general, every group homomorphism $\phi \colon \mathbf Z \to G$ to a profinite group $G$ can be uniquely extended to a continuous group homomoprhism $\hat\phi \colon \hat{\mathbf Z} \to G$, by the same argument: define $\hat\phi((a_n)n)$ to be $(\phi(1)^{a{\lvert G/N\rvert}}){N \trianglelefteq G} \in \lim{N \trianglelefteq G} G/N$ (the limit being over all open normal subgroups).
